# PHP Session Variable not being passed to JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, session

I'm trying to save a PHP Session variable called user_login in a JS variable called name. I need to get the value from the session variable. Nothing worked so far and all I am getting passed to my alert is:

```
<?php echo rawurlencode($_SESSION['user_login']); ?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var name = decodeURIComponent("<?php echo rawurlencode($_SESSION['user_login']); ?>");

  alert(name);

  setTimeout(function() {
  
    if (name.length > 0) {
      $('h3.name').html(name);
      $('h3.name').css({
        display: 'block'
      });
    }

  }, 200);

});
```

Comment: Is the session set correctly?

Comment: @tschaefermedia it is set correctly

Comment: Why do you use rawurlencode? 
To encode special chars? Better use htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the php code isn`t evaluated.

Check if the php works for this file.

The source of the page being served by the web server should look like this:

```
    **decodeURIComponent("some value");**
```

Comment: That works fine, but whenever I try to write php code inside of js files, the js renders them as strings, instead treating it as php... :/

Comment: I'll just use PHP for it, won't bother trying with JS anymore. Thanks for answering